# Promote button is missing (Sitecore XC 101)

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation

I'm following a tutorial online to set up a catalog in my `Sitecore XC` application. Still, at some point, I've noticed that my application is missing the promote button that is supposed to be in a catalog that I have created.

Does anyone know how I can access this button?

The expected result:

[image]

The actual result:

[image]

*quicknote: I'm new with Sitecore, so I don't know if this is related to the XC installation or the application that I'm trying to run.*

Comment: Is this catalog already published? If yes then you cannot promote it so you will have to create a new version and then you will be able to promote it.

Comment: No, it isn't published yet. It's a new catalog, I just have created.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

This bug was somehow related to the cache of my application.

Steps that I did:

1. Stop the redis services instance.
2. Delete the redis dump.rdb file.
3. Start the redis services instance.
4. Use Sitecore postman (SitecoreCommerce_DevOps) api's to clean,
   bootstrap and initialize my application.
5. Recreate a new catalog.